# how to resolve promise when function is called? p5.js

Tags: javascript, promise, p5.js

```
var myPromise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
        // idon't want to resolve after 10seconds... i want to resovle it after show_me function get called and finsih it's job.....
      setTimeout(resolve, 10000)
    });


    let xarr = [];
    let yarr = [];
    async function show_me(){
        console.log("called");

        let url = 'http://localhost:3000/get_transaction2';
        let response = await fetch(url);

        let commits = await response.json(); // read response body and parse as JSON
        for(let i= 0; i<commits.length; i++){
            let lastdate = commits[i].last_date;
            let cl = commits[i].collect_location.split(' ');
            let battery = commits[i].battery_left;
            let broked = commits[i].broken;

            collect_point = new jsPoint(cl[0],cl[1]);

            var font=new jsFont("arial","bold","10px");
            gr.drawText(`${cl}`,new jsPoint(cl[0],cl[1]),font,bluePen.color,90);
            // let x = cl[0] -700;
            // let y = -(Number(cl[1])) -400;
            let x = cl[0];
            let y = -(Number(cl[1]))
            console.log(x,y);

            xarr[i] = x;
            yarr[i] = y;


            if(battery<77 || Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2)>=Math.pow(290,2)){

                plotPointsred(collect_point);
            }
            if(broked == 1){
                plotPointsgreen(collect_point);
            }

        }


        var greenPen=new jsPen(new jsColor("yellow"),5);
        gr.drawCircle(greenPen,new jsPoint(700,-400),290);

    }



    var cities = [];

    var recordDistance;
    var bestEver;
   async function setup() {
        await myPromise;
        s = createCanvas(1000, windowHeight);
        s.position(0,0);
        s.style('z-index','1');
        console.log("did it worked?");
        for (var i = 0; i < xarr.length; i++) {
            var v = createVector(xarr[i], yarr[i]);
            cities[i] = v;
        }

        var d = calcDistance(cities);
        recordDistance = d;
        bestEver = cities.slice();
      }
```

this is p5.js thing what i want to do is following

i want setup() to wait until  --> show_me() get called and finish its job AND THEN resolve the promise(dosen't have to be promise anyway will do good for me if i can make setup() to wait until show_me get called and finish)  so setup() can do its job.

if you are not familiar with p5.js thing, here is my issue. i set a function to resolve promise after 10 seconds because setup() function get called immediately when i open my index.html. setTimeout() function is only option that i know how to delay resolving promise.

i am not good at english so let me know if something doesn't make sense to you.
thank your for reading i am always appreciating stackoverflow thank you

Comment: Why not simply call `resolve()` near the end of your `show_me` function? It's content is async but uses await, so it runs from top to bottom, in order.

Comment: Pretty much the only time you need to use the Promise constructor is when what you have to work with is callback-based. Here, `fetch` returns a promise, and your `show_me` returns a promise, you can simply `await` it (or alternatively `.then(/*...*/)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `show_me` function with `await` and `resolve` after `show_me` is finished like @Chris suggested in the comments.

```
var myPromise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
  await show_me();
  resolve();
});
```

But to be honest, why would you use a Promise to check if another Promise is done?
Doing the example below would get the same results.

```
async function setup() {
  await show_me(); // Instead of await myPromise
  ...
```